# Android RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a recyclerView inside a constraint layout and I cannot make it scroll, the list just continues below the screen without scroll possibility. If I turn the layout into relative layout the scroll works fine.

how can I get it to scroll?

the the following XML shows my layout, the recycler view is in the bottom.  the layout has an image and description at the top of the screen. this screen setup takes 30% of the screen. followed by and a separator and the recycler view that should take the rest of the screen and that cannot scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gradient_top">

   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLock"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewPermissionsTitle"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_phone_lock"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewPermissionsTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:text="@string/allow_permissions"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/description_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewSeparator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/bright_blue"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPermissions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewSeparator" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

For a `RecyclerView` to scroll, one of two things must be true:

- The `RecyclerView` has a smaller height than all of its items
- The `RecyclerView` is inside a scrolling parent

`ConstraintLayout` is not a scrolling parent, so we have to make sure that the `RecyclerView` is "too small", which will cause it to let the user scroll its children.

The easiest way is to just give the `RecyclerView` a defined height, with something like this:

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Of course, this only works if you know ahead of time exactly how big you want your `RecyclerView` to be, and this is not usually the case.

A better solution is to use constraints to define the height of your `RecyclerView`. The first step is to give it a height of `0dp`, which can be thought of as "match constraints". In other words, you're telling the system to make the `RecyclerView` as tall as it needs to be in order to satisfy its top and bottom constrains.

Next, you must define top and bottom constraints. The simplest would be to constrain the `RecyclerView`'s top to the parent's top and its bottom to the parent's bottom. That might look like this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Or, you could position the `RecyclerView` relative to some other views. That might look like this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewAboveMe"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewBelowMe"
```

As long as you combine a height of `0dp` with both top and bottom constraints (and as long as your `RecyclerView` is actually smaller than its contents), this will allow your `RecyclerView` to scroll as desired.

### Original

Your `RecyclerView` is using `wrap_content` for its height. If you want it to scroll, you must provide a fixed height, or, inside a `ConstraintLayout`, use `0dp` for its height and give it an `app:layout_constraintBottom_xxx` attribute.

Comment: it works! however I don't understand why, how does the 0dp help to scroll, and why doesn't it work with wrap_content

Comment: If you use `wrap_content`, the recycler will make itself as tall as required to wrap everything... but the parent will cut the bottom of it off. If you use 0dp plus a constraint bottom, you're making the recyclerview _smaller_ than its contents... and now the scrolling properties of recyclerview kick in.

Comment: i did not got idea about **app:layout_constraintBottom_xxx** could you please explain

Comment: @Nazimch In order to support scrolling, your `RecyclerView` must have some fixed height (that is smaller than its contents). Specifically inside a `ConstraintLayout`, you could provide a height of `0dp` and then provide `app:layout_constraintTop_xxx="@id/some_other_view"` and also `app:layout_constraintBottom_xxx="@id/some_other_view"` (where "xxx" could be replaced by `toBottomOf` or `toTopOf` etc). This will "constrain" the `RecyclerView` and define its size. I mentioned only the bottom constraint because the question already provided a top constraint.

Comment: I spent hours trying everything to get the `RecycleView` to work correctly. Whenever there were more items in it than would fit the alotted space it would just overflow. `match_parent` and `wrap_content` would both act like the `RecycleView` was the only element present, so items would be drawn from top to bottom of the screen over other elements. Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: I don't know why, but in some cases setting the recyclerView height to 0dp and all its vertical constraints doesn't work. I managed to make it scroll horizontally by replacing ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout and setting heights to match_parent both on the parent and the recyclerview itself

Comment: For me helped putting `width="0dp"` for the recycler. Necessary top&bottom constraints were put, the height was set to 0dp, but didn't help. From colleague heard that `match_parent` is not recommended in `ConstraintLayout` and changed the width as well and it worked :)

Comment: @EduardsPozarickis I've used the same solution. It works fine. Seems 0dp is both the proper width and height for scrollable views inside constraint layout.

Comment: layout height 0dp helped me

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it happens because of not constraining bottom of recycler view. Which causes recycler view to be of an infinite height that goes beyond the visible screen.

Answer (score 3):

In RecyclerView, below changes worked for me.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/idBelowView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idAboveView" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        ..... other controls ....

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem by the following XML structure pattarn -

```
                 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       /*be carefull about the height.It need to be match parent.*/
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
                      Others views are here .....
        
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp" /*Must be 0dp in height*/
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
                            /*Must have a layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf */
                            *emphasized text*/>
        
                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```