# I can't scroll the recyclerview even though it display all of the items

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview

`Recyclerview` shows all the items, but I can't scroll it. Also in a way that I can't understand, once I click and open the `searchView`, I'm able to scroll just a bit (still not fully). How can I get the `recyclerview` to scroll?

**Here is the Constraint Layout that includes Recycler View**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:text="@string/notes"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SearchView
        android:queryHint="@string/search"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.search"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_view" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_insert_link_24"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreateNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"/>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And here is the Recyclerview Adapter**

````
class NotesAdapter() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder>() {
    var listener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    var arrList = ArrayList<Notes>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NotesViewHolder {
        return NotesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_rv_notes, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrList.size
    }

    fun setData(arrNotesList: List<Notes>) {
        arrList = arrNotesList as ArrayList<Notes>
    }

    fun setOnClickListener(listener1: OnItemClickListener) {
        listener = listener1
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NotesViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.tvTitle.text = arrList[position].title
        holder.itemView.tvDesc.text = arrList[position].noteText
        holder.itemView.tvDateTime.text = arrList[position].dateTime

        if (arrList[position].color != null){
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrList[position].color))
        }else{
            holder.itemView.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(R.color.ColorLightBlack.toString()))
        }

        if (arrList[position].pathImage != null) {
            holder.itemView.imgNote.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(arrList[position].pathImage))
            holder.itemView.imgNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            holder.itemView.imgNote.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        if (arrList[position].webLink != "") {
            holder.itemView.tvWebLink.text = arrList[position].webLink
            holder.itemView.tvWebLink.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            holder.itemView.tvWebLink.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        holder.itemView.cardView.setOnClickListener {
            listener!!.onClicked(arrList[position].pld!!)
        }

    }

    class NotesViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

    }


    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onClicked(noteId: Int)
    }

}```
````

Comment: What happens when you change the `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` attribute inside the RecyclerViewWidget to `true`?

Comment: @Tonnie Nothing as far as I can see

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397199/android-recyclerview-in-constraintlayout-doesnt-scroll

Comment: Your recycler view does NOT have a bottom constrain and it wraps content.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the .xml content inside the Drawer layout

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
           android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
           android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
           android:text="@string/notes"
           android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
           android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

       <SearchView
           android:queryHint="@string/search"
           android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.search"
           android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
           android:id="@+id/search_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
           android:background="@drawable/background"
           android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv1" />


       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
           android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           android:overScrollMode="never"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_view" />
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/l1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
   
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
               app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image_24"
               app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />
           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_insert_link_24"
               app:tint="@color/ColorWhite" />
  

       </LinearLayout>
   </FrameLayout>

   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabCreateNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem isn't in the scrolling itself, but that the rest of the `RecyclerView` items can't be seen as they are behind the `l1` `LinearLayout`.

To fix this you can adjust the `ConstraintLayout` constraints to attach a `RecyclerView` bottom constraints to the top of the `l1`, and make the height as `0dp` to match constraints:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/l1"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/search_view" />
```